# performance effects of reading from another thread in c++ code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to understand the performance effects of a monitoring mechanism I'm hoping to use in a large c++ program.

I have a container of pointers to doubles from all over the program, and I have a separate thread that "watches" these doubles and prints their latest value whenever they update.

If one of the doubles quickly changes twice (e.g. 2->3->4), I don't care about missing the 3. If one of them changes and then changes back (e.g. 2->3->2), I also don't care if the entire update is missed. The only thing I do care about is that the final value eventually gets printed. The primary concern here is that this have an absolutely minimal effect on the performance of the main program, which is constantly reading and writing these doubles in somewhat arbitrary order.

Below I have what I believe is a working example program, but what I don't know is what sort of performance effects this could have. I have done a bit of benchmarking on toy examples and it doesn't seem to hurt significantly, but I'm concerned my toy examples don't bring out the effect like a large program could. Worst case response latencies will be very important here, so I want to make sure this mechanism is reasonable before I build too much of a system around it.

What I'm really interested in is a bit of education. Why would looking at the value from a different thread have any effect on performance at all? I put in a 100 millisecond sleep to alleviate the effect, but I may be missing part of the theory on why it even matters on a system with multiple CPUs. Are there interesting caching effects in play?

Lastly, is there anything I should change to make the monitor have less of an effect?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Record {
  volatile double& target_;
  double last_;
  std::string name_;
};

void monitor(std::vector<Record> records) {
  while (true) {
    for (auto& record : records) {
      double target = record.target_;
      if (record.last_ != target) {
        std::cout << record.name_ << ' ' << target << std::endl;
        record.last_ = target;
      }
    }

    // does this throttling help anything?
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v(5, -1);

  std::vector<Record> records;
  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i) {
    records.push_back({v[i], v[i], "v[" + std::to_string(i) + "]"});
  }
  std::thread(monitor, records).detach();

  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i) {
    // Can the presence of the monitor slow down this write? (or a read?)
    v[i] = i; 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));    
  }
}
```

clarification:

The reason I'm looping over everything instead of using synchronization is that I have plenty of cores sitting around doing nothing and I want to minimize the work done by the main writer thread.

The reason I used double instead of std::atomic is that I wanted to be able to write the main program using standard primitive types and then "register" certain doubles for monitoring (at startup), but then just use them normally in the main program. It seems I might not be able to rely on atomic writes though.

Comment: You better have some kind of mutex on these data structures.

Comment: why? I thought writes to doubles would be atomic on modern 64bit architecture? I certainly can't afford mutexes here.

Comment: I would check that out before assuming anything.

Comment: `std::atomic<double>` to ensure that it is atomic.

Comment: Note that using `std::atomic<double>` will probably slow down the whole processing in the main loop quite a bit [if it updates the `target_` a lot]. This is due to the "exclusive" use of the value, meaning that ALL processor(core)s have to be informed that "I want to be the single owner of this value". This may need to be done on EVERY access, and at the very least on any access where the same cache-line has been used by another processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read my entire post, I have important things below the "answer to your actual question".

The immediate effect of reading data that is in the cache of another processor (CPU, core, or whatever you call it) is that the cache-content has to be transferred to the other CPU. The efficiency/inefficiency of this varies for different processor architectures. In the worst case the data has to be written to actual RAM, in other cases, it goes to some intermediate cache, or gets transferred on some internal "interprocessor communication channel". The overall effect is, potentially, that the cache-entry is flushed on the "sending" processor, but it's often better.

Writes to the same cache-line (`last_ = x`) will also affect the other processor, by flushing that cache-line, so now the other processor has to reload the `target_` value, even if it hadn't changed. Again, the details of how "bad" this is depends on the exact processor architecture and sometimes the system design (how fast and what kind of memory, for example).

However, your code is NOT at all sound in a generic sense:

- The effect of reading/writing data that is NOT atomic is unpredictable (and at least implementation defined, if not undefined, behaviour), and depends on the actual processor architecture. It is not guaranteed that reading `target_` in your example will be done atomically, so you could get random garbage as the "result". This can lead to all sorts of problems, including crashing of the application, because, for example, two halfs of the actual data contains inconsistent floating point data, and causes a FP exception that is taken by the processor.
- Beware that `for (auto& record : records) {` is not safe if another thread is updating the `records` vector - it may for example re-allocate the entire vector content, and your current data gets re-used for other purposes.

Comment: are there any architectures where these writes would be atomic? is there a static_assert I could use to check?

Comment: Properly atomic, probably only single core processors. atomic as in "not splitting the read", I know x86 with 64-bit data bus would do this atomically then (as long as the value is aligned to 8 bytes of course). Don't think there is any easy way to determine that as part of the compile process - how portable do you want your code? The REAL solution, however, to your problem is to "find another solution".

Comment: Thanks Mats!  I need almost no portability and this runs on x86_64. So what I'm taking from this is that although on my architecture it should actually work correctly, I need to be very concerned about the caching effects you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample code, there are several performance/safety concerns that you should be aware of:

- Since the monitor thread should never write to the double value in the vector use a const double& reference instead of double&. Also get rid of the 'volatile' keyword, this is not what you want unless the memory where the double is stored is modified outside your code.
- Iterating through ALL the values in the vector to find modified values is a CPU-intensive and very inefficient method. Basically you are using poll instead of push notification to let the monitor thread know when values change.

Use condition variables to wake up the monitor thread when a change happens. Here is a tutorial on how to use condition variables - http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/04/c11-concurrency-tutorial-advanced-locking-and-condition-variables.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The reason I chose not to use condition variables is that I didn't want to burden the main thread with any extra work. I have 32 cores to work with and most of them are sitting idle, so I'm more than happy to burn one of them on this monitor. my primary concern here is not slowing down the main thread.

Comment: And you're absolutely right about the const reference. That was just an oversight in the example I wrote for stack overflow.

Comment: Think about it this way - say your writer modified element n and your monitor is iterating at n+1, n+2, ... etc. Your monitor thread just missed this update and will not get it until it loops again. Now imagine this with 1M, 10M, 100M elements and how much CPU you are burning for no reason. But again, this is all premature optimization. I suggest run this code on the target machine with a representative sample of the data and let the profiler tell you the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this probably "works" like you think it does, but is not going to have the performance you want and there are many ways to write this type of functionality better.

In general there are a few problems:

1. Can't scale (race conditions / performance issues)
2. CPU hog (due to infinite looping. Signal/Wait or a Semaphore could fix this, but this breaks if you do a 2->3->2 update because it won't notice the change in order to signal back).
3. O(n) to change a single value (with a funny edge case where you can change it back before it notices what happens)

Look into synchronization primitives and mutual exclusion. If you haven't implemented the producer/consumer pattern before, that would be useful to learn.

While it's tempting to try to optimize this in a multi-threaded way, the real answer is that this isn't a problem where parallel processing will be a good solution.

EDIT: Here's a toy problem that may be of value to you:
  Have a size 10000 queue of doubles that a single thread inserts random doubles into the queue when it is not full.
  Have 10 threads that pop from the queue and output whether or not it is a prime number.